# Spring JPA performance issue when saving with EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I'm new to Spring JPA, bear with me if I did something wrong.

I have a Repository DAO for executing some native query:

```
@Repository
public class TestingDAO {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void createNewFoos(Long fooId, Long barId) {
        if (ebuId == null) return;
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO FOO_BAR(foo_id, bar_id) values (" + fooId + "," + barId + ")";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(insertQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

FOO_BAR is a relation table with 2 FK.
I realized that the execution time of createNewFoos method keeps increasing when I call it multiple times in one transaction (for 10,000 th, it even takes some seconds). When I use JPA Repository to save the entity object (result in db is the same), there is no performance issue like that.

Could you please explain why does it happen? Am I did something wrong?

Thanks in advance for you helps!

Comment: how do you measure this performance?

Comment: I simply use a log to measure it.